# Probability of winning a best of 5 game series given that the first game is lost.

Tags: probability

> Probability of winning a best of $5$ game series given that the first game is lost.

Assuming that the two teams (A and B) are equally likely to win a game and the games are independent events, so I considered it like this:

If the first game team A loses $L????$, they must win $3$ out of the remaining $4$ games, so I got $\binom43$ ways that this could happen.
I then divided it by the total number of ways to win $3$ out of the $5$ games $\binom53$, I then get $\binom43/\binom53$ as my final answer. Is this method appropriate?

Comment: What about winning 4 games? In the title you specified "Probability of winning a *best* of 5 game series"

Comment: I don't understand the division, nor am I clear who "they" refers to. There are $4$ games left to be played.  Assuming "they" means "$A$" then the probability that $A$ wins at least three of them is $\binom 43 \times \frac 1{2^4}+\binom 44 \times \frac 1{2^4}$.  Note:  convince yourself that it's fine to imagine that all $4$ remaining games are played, even if the series might be decided prior to game $\#5$.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, I understand now

Answer (score 1):

Your method isn’t quite right. There are indeed $\binom{4}{3}$ ways for the remaining 4 games to play out. But the probabilities for each possibility are determined as a binomial distribution:

$\Pr(LWWW) =\frac{1}{16}$

$\Pr(WLWW) =\frac{1}{16}$

$\Pr(WWLW) =\frac{1}{16}$

$\Pr(WWW) =\frac{1}{8}$ (Here the 5th game is not played.)

Then sum the probabilities to get a final answer of $\frac{5}{16}$.